# Buddypress Groups profile Tab Menu not reordering

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I Write a filter to reorder all the Menu inside the buddypress Groups Profile Page

```
function reorder_setup_nav()
{
     global $bp;
     $bp->bp_options_nav[$bp->groups->current_group->slug]['home']['position'] = 200;
     $bp->bp_options_nav[$bp->groups->current_group->slug]['members']['position'] = 199;
     $bp->bp_options_nav[$bp->groups->current_group->slug]['send-invites']['position'] = 198;
     $bp->bp_options_nav[$bp->groups->current_group->slug]['forum']['position'] = 197;
     $bp->bp_options_nav[$bp->groups->current_group->slug]['media']['position'] = 10;
}
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'reorder_setup_nav', 100000 );
```

Here is my code , the problem I'm facing is this filter not reordering media menu alone . 
I need to bring the media menu in first place. Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I got solution while using this filter. :)

```
add_action( 'bp_init', 'reorder_setup_nav', 999 );
```